# Was the US Naval base at Guantanamo Bay actually important in 1985? And was it in any danger?

Tags: 20th-century, cold-war, cuba, movies

In the real world case that *A Few Good Men* is based on, in 1985 part of the guard for the base was a group called "The Ten" that went through grueling physical training in order to guard a fence. In the movie, everyone acts as if it's common knowledge that the base is providing freedom and protection to United States citizens. Was this just delusional, or would the average person have agreed with that in 1985? If they moved the base to actual US territory like Florida or Puerto Rico would it have changed anything at all?

Specifically I'm curious about the big climactic rant, and whether it's more a man doing an important job and saving lives but in an immoral way, or a man who's completely out of touch that he's in charge of high-end security guards for a fence no-one is attacking at a base that doesn't matter?

> Son, we live in a world that has walls, and those walls have to be guarded by men with guns. Who's gonna do it? You? You, Lieutenant Weinberg? I have a greater responsibility than you can possibly fathom. You weep for Santiago, and you curse the Marines. You have that luxury. You have the luxury of not knowing what I know -- that Santiago's death, while tragic, probably saved lives; and my existence, while grotesque and incomprehensible to you, saves lives.
>
> You don't want the truth because deep down in places you don't talk about at parties, you want me on that wall -- you need me on that wall.
>
> We use words like "honor," "code," "loyalty." We use these words as the backbone of a life spent defending something. You use them as a punch line.
>
> I have neither the time nor the inclination to explain myself to a man who rises and sleeps under the blanket of the very freedom that I provide and then questions the manner in which I provide it.
>
> I would rather that you just said "thank you" and went on your way. Otherwise, I suggest you pick up a weapon and stand the post.

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done.  Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: I suspect that it is going to be very difficult to select an authoritative answer from those provided; the underlying questions are highly political and subjective.

Comment: Yeah I'd worried about that. Maybe I should rephrase to ask just for a description of the pro-base viewpoint

Comment: Colonel Jessup's job is not just to guard a fence, but to preserve the "health" of his unit. If a few lives must be sacrificed in order to maintain discipline and combat readiness, he seemed to be OK with it.

Comment: If you feel that a tiny nation with a history of exporting revolution, professing an ideology that is based on the elimination of America is a threat, you're likely to believe that Guantanomo is important.  Confirmation bias will be more important than scholarship in reaching that decision.  Setting the movie in that environment makes the ideology of the Colonel more plausible; the choice is probably made on dramatic grounds rather than historical grounds.

Comment: To answer the questions, on could look for cuban attacks or harrasment of the base in the time frame  - since cuban civilians commuted (on foot) into the base up until 2012 I doubt there where any, but worth checking. The film specifically mentions fence shootings, IIRC, where these actually a thing?

Comment: I could find mentions of refugees trying to get in, but no attacks. You're right the film mentions a fence shooting, which is based on part of the actual incident in 1985... but that seems to be a marine firing out from the base, not someone firing in. The man who was beaten (accidentally to death) had told higher-ups that marines were firing out of the base (presumably at civilians).

Comment: I had that thought but then I wasn't sure. I'll keep that in mind, thanks!